# How to download and install sitecore

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I want to explore sitecore CMS more however i am not able to download any trial or free version of sitecore.

Is there any community edition or free version provided by sitecore?

Comment: dont even bother using sitecore. horrible cms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore software is available for the sitecore certified developers for tryout purpose ro you should be the sitecore partner. You could also purchase sitecore by contacting them. If you are an sitecore certified developer then the tool can be downloaded in [sitecore developer portal](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform.aspx).

There is no free or community edition for sitecore as of now.

Checkout my blog which lets you know on [how to install and Configure Sitecore sitecore 8.1](https://itsmycode.com/how-to-install-and-configure-sitecore/) CMS tool on windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must be a Sitecore certified developer or work for a partner to install it.

You can find training here: http://www.sitecore.net/services-and-support/training/back-end-developers/wnd8-sitecore-website-development-for-net-developers.aspx

The site to download the goodies is here: https://dev.sitecore.net/

You will also need a license key which your parter company can give you.